# Customize Rails Scaffold Generator Templates for Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I have a rails app with an Admin interface. My admin views and controllers are under a /admin directory. I'd like to customize the scaffold generator erb templates so that it generates the end user views and a set of admin views (as they are different in styling, etc...).

I know you can copy `index.html.erb` for instance to `your-project/lib/templates/erb/scaffold` and running `rails g scaffold admin::blog` generates the admin files needed. Is there a way to have two separate `index.html.erb` scaffold templates, one for the front end and one for the admin?

Comment: You can write custom generators for Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: If you are asking how to make different views for admin versus normal users, you could use conditional statements in your .html.erb files or you could require that a user is an admin before being able to enter a page.